# JavaScript cross-browser: Is it safe to treat a string as array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, cross-browser

Is this code safe in all major browsers?

```
var string = '123'
alert(string[1] == '2') // should alert true
```

Comment: jw. why do you want to do that, this is just as optimized. Not bashing... just curious.
alert(string.indexOf("2") != -1);

Comment: @Tim: because that's not the same thing? Your condition checks if it appears in the string at all.  He is checking the value of a specific position in the string. If you did string.indexOf("2") == 1) that would be the same thing.

Comment: @Tim When you do IndexOf('2') != -1.  All this tells you is that '2' exists somewhere in the string.  It does not verify that '2' is index 1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it's not safe. Internet Explorer 7 doesn't support accessing strings by index.

You have to use the `charAt` method to be compatibale with IE7:

```
var string = '123';
alert(string.charAt(1) == '2');
```

Comment: Awesome catch Guffa. I had no clue IE 7 didnt support strings by index.

Comment: I thought it worked in everything -- well done for finding that

Answer (score 3):

Everything in JavaScript is an object; arrays, functions, strings, everything. The piece of code you put up is perfectly valid, although a little confusing - there are much better ways of doing that

```
var str = '123';
str[1] === '2'; // true, as you've just discovered (if you're not in IE7)
// Better ways:
str.indexOf('2'); // 1
str.charAt(1); // '2'
str.substr(1, 1); // '2'
str.split(''); // ['1', '2', '3']
```

The better ways make sure anyone else reading your code (either someone else or yourself in 6 months time) don't thing that `str` is an array. It makes your code a lot easier to read and maintain

Comment: Agreed. It's valid but it might make people think you are using an array instead of a string. Would not want to sacrifice that code readability esp when there are many other less ambiguous methods.

Comment: the indexOf method is NOT implemented for arrays in every browser ( cough cough IE cough cough )

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` has limited but growing support. `String.prototype.indexOf` has been around for a while.

Comment: Accessing a string by index is not supported by all current browsers either. (IE7 sadly still has to be considered to be current...)

Comment: I've updated my notes. I gave you +1 for spotting that, Guffa

Comment: Accessing characters as numeric properties of strings is non-standard as well as not universally supported. A string is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

I tested in IE7, IE8, Safari, Chrome, and FF. All worked just fine!

EDIT
just for kicks it works in Konqueror also!
[Js Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sTCrY/)

Comment: How did you do to test it in IE7? I tested it in IE7 and it *doesn't* work.

Comment: coughcough IE8/7 compatible != IE7 cough

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see why you can't do that...though alternatively, you can use .substring()

Answer (score 0):

It will work.  It might be a problem if you decide to use browser specific functions (I.E `xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` only works in internet explorer)