# Ie7 javascript issue

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have following code its working one IE8, FF and other browser but is not working for IE7
on checking i found `formatIncludes[i]` is not working, any idea whats wrong in this with IE7 and any work around

```
var formatIncludes = valueToSet.replace(/[^\D]/g, '');
    for(var i=formatIncludes.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--){
        if(valueToSet && valueToSet != null && valueToSet.endsWith(formatIncludes[i])){
            valueToSet = valueToSet.substr(0, valueToSet.length - 1);
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return (this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) != -1);
};
```

`formatIncludes` can contain any string value

error on IE7

```
Message: 'length' is null or not an object
Line: 352
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:7001/HHSPortal/framework/skeletons/hhsa/js/util.js
```

Comment: `formatIncludes` is an array? I don't think so.

Comment: What's `endWith`, I think we need the code for that to be able to tell. What's the error on console?

Comment: @MuthuKumaran No, but you can still do indexing like that on a string. The better solution is to use `.charAt(i)` instead.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran: Strings are _array-like_, the index look-up should work.

Comment: @ianpgall - it worked can u put it as an answer so that i can accept it

Comment: @All - but why it was not working using indexing

Comment: I wish I could tell you...haha

Comment: Oh I got it now. Thanks @ianpgall and @ elclanrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that indexing a string with `[i]` does not work? And the more consistent/correct solution is to use `.charAt(i)`

The reasoning can be found in these:

[string.charAt(x) or string[x]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx)

[JavaScript cross-browser: Is it safe to treat a string as array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599881/javascript-cross-browser-is-it-safe-to-treat-a-string-as-array)

Comment: any idea why `[i]` doesnt work on IE7 though it works on other browsers

Comment: It might just be another one of those wonderful standards that IE decides to implement... :)

Comment: @ianpgall or neglect in this case

Comment: @Phil Haha I meant a fictional standard they decided to create that says `[]` is not allowed with strings. But true

Comment: @Varun Nevermind, found some sources online for this problem, updated my answer

Comment: @ianpgall - they just changed the question to look as an answer :D